# SSIS Excel Source connection and setting of package variable

Tags: ssis

Newbie to SSIS.  I want to read an Excel spreadsheet, get a value, assign it to a package variable, and then use the variable in a SQL statement.  I can read the excel and get the value, cannot figure out how to put the value into a variable (from the Excel source) so the SQL will run.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest thing would probably be to have the excel source point to a RecordSet Destination. You can then Foreach-loop the object holding the recordset and extract the value(s) you want to work with that originated from Excel.